# Product in cohomology and homology $(\xi \times \eta) \frown ( x \times y) = (-1)^{p_2 q_1}(\xi \frown x) \times (\eta \frown y)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Suppose $\xi \in H^{p_2}(X),\eta \in H^{q_2}(Y),x \in H_{p_1+p_2}(X),y \in H_{q_1+q_2}(Y)$. Then 
$$(\xi \times \eta) \frown ( x \times y) = (-1)^{p_2 q_1}(\xi \frown x) \times (\eta \frown y)$$

Cross product is defined by *Eilenberg-Zilber* homotopy equivalence. That is 
\begin{align}
 S^{p}(X) + S^{q}(Y) &\overset{\otimes}\rightarrow S^{p}(X) \otimes S^q(Y) \overset{Eilenberg-Zilber}{\longrightarrow} S^{p+q}(X \times Y)\\
(x,y) &\mapsto x\otimes y \mapsto EZ(x\otimes y)
\end{align}
(So as in $S_*(X)$)

And cap product is given by
\begin{align}
S^q(X) \times S_{p+q} \overset{\frown}\longrightarrow S_p\\
\xi \frown \sigma = \sideset{_p}{}{\sigma} \langle\xi,\sigma_q\rangle
\end{align}
where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is Kronecker product.

We can make *EZ* homtopy equivalence concrete by construct
\begin{align}
S^{p+q}(X \times Y) &\overset{Eilenberg-Zilber}{\longrightarrow} S^{p}(X) \otimes S^q(Y)\\
\sigma &\mapsto \sum_{i+j = p+q}\rho_1(\sideset{_i}{}{\sigma}) \otimes \rho_2(\sigma_j)
\end{align}.

Therefore
$$(\xi \times \eta) \frown ( x \times y) = \sideset{_{p_1+q_1}}{}{(EZ(x\otimes y))} \langle EZ^{\sharp}(\xi\otimes \eta) ,(EZ(x\otimes y))_{p_2+q_2} \rangle$$

The difficulty is $(EZ(x\otimes y))_{p_2+q_2}$ which is obtained by truncating last $p_2+q_2$ dimensional face. This operation is not a chain map.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Prove the equality in the title

Comment: What are $p$ and $q$ with respect to $p_1,q_1,\ldots$?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I've edited

Comment: I don't have much time right now but it feels like you should be able to swap the last $p_2$ vertices of $x$ and the first $q_1$ vertices of $y$ at the cost of the $-$ sign, in the spirit of what is done to prove that the cap product is graded commutative.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier What do you mean by commutative? I thought who has commutativity is only cup product not cap product.

Comment: Cup. I meant cup. Sorry about that.